# What tool does ubuntu official use to build ubuntu distro iso

Tags: daily-build

What tool does ubuntu official use to build the newest distro (just like debian use live-build to do this work) iso ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ISOs are built by [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) using [Ubuntu CD Images](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage)

You login to a ubuntu.com web page & can cause an ISO build job to kick off if you cannot wait for the next *cron* job to kick off a daily (*assuming you logged in with an ID with authority to do so*).

What you're specifically asking for is https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-cdimage

Comment: I have cloned ubuntu-cdimage, the README inside is too brief, is there any detail usage guide？

Comment: Sorry I've only used the online interface on the ubuntu.com page(s) (*links of which gets pasted somewhat regularly; used it myself as reference yesterday on another question*)  The *build* process is documented in manyy places including the Ubuntu wiki; a recent response I gave you may find helpful is [here](https://discourse.lubuntu.me/t/how-is-the-lubuntu-system-created/4759/2) which dealt with Lubuntu specifically (*same processes build all Ubuntu ISOs including flavors*). Maybe start reading at "*Nusakan vs Launchpad*" & "*debian-cd*", then "*livecd-rootfs*" etc..

Comment: I executed "for-project kubuntu cron.daily-live --live" as mentioned in README, i got "... cannot create live filesystem builds owned by Ubuntu CD Image Team" respone in the log，how can i avoid this error ?