How do I replicate the automated system used to build the Ubuntu iso file?
So I came across this article, which says the following:

An automated system builds CD and DVD images based on the packages in the archive. Its log files are available from http://people.ubuntu.com/~ubuntu-archive/cd-build-logs/, and the set of packages included on them is driven by the seeds.

and I wanted to know how I can replicate that automated system in my own machine so I can create the iso file the exact same way the one that gets released is created.

Maybe helpful  - ISOs are built by launchpad processors using Ubuntu CD Image (see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1507165/what-tool-does-ubuntu-official-use-to-build-ubuntu-distro-iso/1507171#1507171), but I'm not sure how easy it would be to replicate those same procedures on a local system  (I assume you're not using launchpad on your machine)
